# How cakephp2 call method another helper to current helper?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have created helper name TicketHelper (has TicketsController), CommonHelper (no controller) and ExcelHelper (no controller). Inside TicketHelper it work fine when called any function of CommonHelper. Here example TicketHelper:

```
<?php
    class TicketHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Session','Common');
    public function myFunction(){

        echo $this->Common->workfine();
    }
?>
```

By the same action i called CommonHelper to ExcelHelper it produces error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function workfine() on a non-object in

Answer (score 2):

After many hours check, i found mistake problem with constructor

```
<?php
   class TicketHelper extends AppHelper {
   public $helpers = array('Session','Common');
   public function myFunction(){
    echo $this->Common->workfine();
   }

   //Here my problem constructor Note: function name and class name are the same 
   function TicketHelper (){
          //My code here
   }

   /**
    * It should be follow cakephp doc
    * function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    *        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    *       
    *  }
    *
    */
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a helper inside a controller. A helper is used for logic in the view. It is included in the controller but accessible in the view. For logic shared between controllers, use a component instead http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component.

If you still want to use a helper in the controller (not recommended):

```
$view = new View($this);
$myHelper = $view->loadHelper('MyHelper');
```

Comment: Sure, I am not use in controller, i just want create a helper and wanted call another function from other helper.